# Supervised Machine Learning for .Net

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I have a problem whereby our users receive the balance of an account each day, and based on the balance, perform an action.

Given the list of historical balances and resulting actions, is it possible to use machine learning to predict the future actions? Preferably in the .net platform.

Thanks.
Ark

Answer (score 0):

I've never used .NET for any data analytics, but I'm sure it won't be too terribly difficult to transpose what I say here into logic in .NET

One of the things people don't like about data sciences is that in order to see if something IS actually possible (predicting future outcomes in this case), you need to do a lot of exploring with the data and see if the data has enough of a pattern to be learned (by either human or by a ML algorithm).

The way to do this would be to shuffle and split the data in some way...let's say into one group with 70 percent of the data and a second with 30 percent of the data.
Once you do this, you want to train some algorithm with the first group (training set) and use the second group(test set) to verify the accuracy of your algorithm.
So how do you chose an algorithm? That's the trickiest part. Only you can say which is best for your particular scenario given full access to the data. However, given that your output seems to be very discrete (let's say max 5 actions), that makes this a supervised learning classification problem. I'd do some analysis using one of these algorithms (SVM, kNN, and DecisionsTrees are a few popular ones), and use some error LIKE F1 or R^2 to determine how well your fitted algorithm performs on your test set.

Answer (score 0):

To perform supervised Machine Learning in .NET, the ML.NET Framework has been [announced](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/introducing-ml-net-cross-platform-proven-and-open-source-machine-learning-framework/), and a preview is now available (as of 7th May 2018).

A good starting place for ML.NET is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/machine-learning-and-ai/ml-dotnet/get-started/windows).